# Using a new Python IDE but use the Anaconda Python interpreter

Tags: python, anaconda

I have downloaded the Anaconda distro which come with many useful "accessories" (Jupyter notebook, etc.) and a Python interpreter.

I am planning to now download a new IDE, PyCharm, and wonder how I can have PyCharm use the Python interpreter that came with Anaconda. Is that possible and easy to do? How?

Or can I download any new free IDE through Anaconda and avoid issues about the Python interpreter?

Comment: It will probably just use it automatically...

Comment: Agreeing with User253751 above; I installed Anaconda on all my machines where I am using Vs Code, Vim, PyCharm, never had to worry about that issue.
Problems may arise when you have multiple venv, but that's another story

Answer (score 0):

You can use EVERY Python IDE with Anaconda.

Here's how to configure PyCharm
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

And take your time to learn your IDE. It's different from Notepad.